# HTML Field security option in Classic SharePoint site

Tags: sharepoint-designer, classic-experience, sharepoint-site, chatbot

I'm trying to embed a code in Classic SharePoint site. I explored and ran a PowerShell script to enable html field security option in Site Collection Administrator. The script ran successfully but the option doesn't show up in the SharePoint site after 24 hours.

Help me

1. To embed a code in SharePoint site without HTML field security option
2. Is there any other way to enable HTML field security in Site Collection Administrator?

Comment: Have you looked at [this article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/allow-or-restrict-the-ability-to-embed-content-on-sharepoint-pages-e7baf83f-09d0-4bd1-9058-4aa483ee137b)?

Comment: With this article mentioned by @MatiurRahman above, you need to enable domain(s) where the referenced code; after this step, no trouble to embed content.

Comment: @AntonioLeonardo,@Matiur Rahman I have already tried all the steps and also the PowerShell scripts. The point is I'm not able to view HTML field security under my Site administrator. Please help me on this

Comment: @ThariqAziz, please, call the SharePoint Admin to give you the necessary permissions or delegate them to make this action for you.